# Parsing a HTML bodyText using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-email

I have an email in HTML format containing text and tables that I am trying to parse using javascript. The text parsing works just fine, I like just have to run a regex to get what I need from the content, e.g.:

```
var name     = mail.bodyText.match(/Name:\s*(.*)/);
```

Now the table part is quite tricky. Say the table contains 3 columns and I only want to retrieve data from the first column where associated data is listed. When I type the following:

```
var column1Data = mail.bodyText.match(/Column1([\s\S]*?)/);
    if (column1Data) {
        var column1DataSplit = sources[1].split("\n");}
}
```

Data is not retrieved.

Example of a html table:

[image]

Any idea on how to retrieve a html table bodyText?

Thanks.

Comment: Not enough information to answer. Can you post an example of the html in question?

Comment: Hi Rocky, I added an image showing an example of that table.

Comment: Is it an option to use jQuery?

Comment: Can you not do something with `document.querySelector('table td:eq(0)')` or something? Also.. hard to answer if we don't know what the HTML looks like.

Comment: I must admit I have no experience in using jQuery. My code is very simple, as the one above. Should I use jQuery for that kind of parsing?

Comment: Sorry, didn't make myself clear. I meant to ask that you post an example of the html as text.

Comment: True it would have been easier for me at first to have the text format, but I don't have it.

Comment: where is `sources` defined? What is the actual thing you're trying to find in the table?

Comment: Actually, it is very simple. As I simply could parse the horizontal html lines. I would like to parse the columns (in a vertical way). Say I'd like to have the list of Names retrieved from the table. And that would be the list {Jane DUBLIN, Spencer HOWLING} under "Name" field. That would have been easier for me if the data was in one line (html wouldn't have bothered, it would have been parsed properly with the code above).

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1220550

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Why not just find the name row in the table?

```
var td = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(1)');
for (var i in td) {
  var nameData = td[i].innerHTML
  if ( i > 0 && nameData ) // skip header row
  console.log(nameData)
}
```

Comment: Jane isn't trying to test if `'Jane Dublin'` is present in the table. The goal is to extract the names. See Jane's comment on the question that starts 'Actually, it is very simple.'.

Comment: see final updated answer, should give you just what you need.

Comment: yeah in the beginning I wasn't sure if you were looking for something more specific.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for your swift replies. But let me put it otherwise: I have no idea what the HTML tables codes are, so my parser acts as if it was the dumbest one ever; it grabs random emails bodyMails and extract whatever it wants from it. Now, luckily there are simple parts that can be extracted easily because the data usually follows its associated tag, say: **Name : Jane**. But when it comes to tables with for one tag you have multiple rows, it becomes tricky and seemingly undoable  with only regex queries.

Comment: If you "have no idea what the HTML tables codes are" how can you possibly parse them? Either you have the html text to parse or you don't have anything to parse. If you want help with this you're going to need to provide at least few examples (html text) of what you want to parse (in your question). Perhaps we can generalize from multiple examples to get a solution that will work for you in all (or at least most) cases.

Answer (score -2):

You haven't provided enough detail in your question for me to be able to give you an answer to your specific problem but it sounds like maybe you're just asking about how to grab the html from the first column in each row of a table. Here is how you could do that.

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r2c1</td>
    <td>r2c2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(1)');
  for (td of tds) {
    console.log(td.innerHTML);
  }
</script>
```

Console output:

```
"r1c1"
"r2c1"
```

https://codepen.io/rockysims/pen/NOJMap?editors=1011